# Excel Interop no longer working when user is logged into Office365

Tags: c#, .net, excel

We developped an application which create an Excel worksheet using a template and then show it on the screen.

Since monday, it seems that this functionality stopped working. The program freeze and is no longer responsive. If I end the excel task, I get "Remote procedure call failed" on "Set_bold". If I remove this line, I get it somewhere else and so on, until it simply stop as ".visible = true", which I can't remove.

If I disconnect the user, the problem stops.

Does anyone have any idea what could be happening ?

EDIT : It seems the problem happens only when I try to use a template (.xlt) file to format it. If I remove this line of code, it works, but it makes the file ugly since there are no formating.